# Installing tar.bz2 file of VLC player

Tags: linux, fedora

I am a new user to Linux. I need to install VLC player in Fedora. I downloaded `tar.bz2` package for VLC player. How do I install this player?

I searched how to install `tar.bz2` and i tried this:

[image]

I don't know what I did; the next instruction was `make install` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not ask about the specific errors instead?

Comment: `yum install vlc`

Answer (score 0):

Use your package manager to install `gcc-c++` - that should give you the compiler you need (CentOS/Fedora etc is `yum install gcc-c++`). You also need to make sure your system has: `libdvbpsi` and `mpeg2dec` (these are required)

You should probably install these as well, to get everything working: `libdvdcss`, `libdvdplay`, `a52dec`, `ffmpeg`, `libmad`, `faad2`, `libogg` and `libvorbis`

You may be able to install VLC from a package manager itself - check this page for info: [Installing VLC](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch03.html)

Answer (score 0):

If 'make' worked, but 'make install' didn't, then you likely need *root* prvileges in order for 'make install' to work because it needs to copy files to system directories. In your terminal, log in as root and then run the command in the VLC installation directory.

```
> su
> make install
```

Or, if you've already set up sudo prvileges for your account use this command instead:

```
> sudo make install
```